# Are there any implications if I receive Australia PR while I am in USA on L1B?

Tags: usa, australia, pr, l1-visa

I am Indian passport holder and got L1B recently. I will be starting my new assignment soon.

Few months ago, I applied for Australia PR (EOI). So what happens if I get the Australian PR invite while I am working in US?

If I visit Australia to activate PR, will my L1B has any impact?

Or As I am on L1B, will there be any issues in Australian PR?

Overall, I would like to know if there are any implications?